# JQuery Firebug illegal char

Tags: jquery, firebug

I have this code snippet:

```
$(function() {
    $('.toolbar [id^=button]').on('click', function () {
        $(this)
            .css('background-color', '#559153')
            .siblings("[id^=button]").css('background-color', '#88e885');

    });

});​
```

Firebug find an illegal char at the end. There is no char.
How can i solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copy and paste it into Firebug's console. Go to the end of the snippet, hit 'end' and then 'backspace'

This will remove an invisible illegal character

Happens to me all the time. Very upsetting!

**EDIT**

I went here: [online escaper](http://www.neoegm.com/tech/online-tools/intelligent-escaper-unescaper-online-unescape-and-escape-tool-with-url-parameter-parsing-and-more/)
and escaped your snippet. You can see `%u200B` at the end there, that's the bastard!